# Vb.net drop SQL Server user and logins

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, authentication, multi-user

I'm creating a fitness management project with multiple SQL Server logins and users. I was successful in creating new logins and it's user using vb.net but now I'm facing an issue with dropping unnecessary logins and users.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance

What I used:

Connection string: `fitnessdb`

```
SqlCommand("Drop user ['"& user_name &"']"
```

Connection string: `master`

```
Sqlcommand("Drop login['"&user_name&"']"
```

I get this exception:

> Cannot drop user because it does not exist or you don not have permission

Comment: The OP appears the actually be talking about `LOGIN`s and `USER`s, not rows, @Julian . Though why they are trying to do that from the application seems wrong; I doubt the end user will be connecting directly to the database.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes.  It looks like these commands don't expect those.

Comment: Instead of giving each user a login to the database itself, it is usual to use a database of users. You might get some useful ideas from [Custom User Management in ASP.NET Core MVC with Identity](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/) (search for ".net identity" for more articles).